# Qt: How to instantiate a class from within a c++ dll without header?

Tags: qt, dll, instantiation

I have a c++ dll. The relevant function, that I want to use is:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void PDFConverterWrapperCpp::convert(QString source, QString target, QString license){...}
```

I also have a factory method, that can instantiate the class 'PDFConverterWrapperCpp':

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) PDFConverterWrapperCpp* create()
{
return new PDFConverterWrapperCpp();
}
```

Now, in the client cpp application I'd like to instantiate the class.

```
QLibrary library("PDFConverterWrapperCpp");
typedef void* (*ConverterObj)(); 
ConverterObj obj = (ConverterObj)library.resolve("create");
if(obj)
{
// Here I'd like to call the constructor obj(), and call the convert(QString, QString, QString) function of the object, but I'm not sure how to manage that.
}
```

If the code is right, I'd like to call the convert function somehow.